# borgbackup : tag A or U when files are updated

Tags: backup

i want to backup /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice folder with borgbackup, it has some xml files and some snapshots (.bimg), as well as qcow2 image.

the image weighs 14 GB.

```
root@kvm610:~ # ls -lh /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice.qcow2
-rwxr-xr-x 1 libvirt-qemu kvm 14G avril 12 07:17 /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice.qcow2*
```

the first borgbackup backup lasts 2m37, all the files are tagged A, because "added".

```
root@kvm610:~ # time borg create --list /var/lib/libvirt/borgbackup/kvm610::trial4 /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice
A /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice_2021-08-28_06:25:22.xml
A /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice_2021-08-23_06:25:35.xml
A /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice_2021-09-02_06:25:03.xml
A /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice_2021-08-26_06:25:35.xml
A /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice_2021-08-29_06:25:14.xml
A /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice_2021-08-30_06:25:17.xml
A /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice_2021-08-31_06:25:26.xml
A /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice_2021-09-01_06:25:10.xml
A /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice_2021-08-22_06:25:08.xml
A /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice_2021-08-24_06:25:51.xml
A /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice_2021-08-25_06:25:23.xml
A /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice_2021-08-27_06:25:14.xml
A /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice.bimg-20210412-141702
A /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice.bimg-20210412-131701
A /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice.bimg-20210412-121701
A /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice.bimg-20210412-111701
A /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice.bimg-20210412-101701
A /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice.bimg-20210412-091701
A /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice.bimg-20210412-081701
A /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice.bimg-20210412-071702
A /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice.qcow2
d /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice

real    2m37,093s
user    1m46,503s
sys    0m11,726s
```

I then restart the same backup, in the same warehouse but with a different archive name (trial5). all the xml and bimg files are tagged U, like "unchanged", but the qcow2 image is still tagged A, even though it hasn't moved ... the VM has been shut down since April.

```
root@kvm610:~ # time borg create --list /var/lib/libvirt/borgbackup/kvm610::trial5 /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice
U /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice_2021-08-28_06:25:22.xml
U /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice_2021-08-23_06:25:35.xml
U /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice_2021-09-02_06:25:03.xml
U /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice_2021-08-26_06:25:35.xml
U /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice_2021-08-29_06:25:14.xml
U /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice_2021-08-30_06:25:17.xml
U /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice_2021-08-31_06:25:26.xml
U /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice_2021-09-01_06:25:10.xml
U /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice_2021-08-22_06:25:08.xml
U /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice_2021-08-24_06:25:51.xml
U /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice_2021-08-25_06:25:23.xml
U /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice_2021-08-27_06:25:14.xml
U /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice.bimg-20210412-141702
U /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice.bimg-20210412-131701
U /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice.bimg-20210412-121701
U /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice.bimg-20210412-111701
U /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice.bimg-20210412-101701
U /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice.bimg-20210412-091701
U /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice.bimg-20210412-081701
U /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice.bimg-20210412-071702
A /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice.qcow2
d /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice

real    2m36,473s
user    1m45,359s
sys    0m11,831s
```

you have an idea to explain this?

and the backup time is the same ... 2m37 / 2m36

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

According to Thorsten Schöning, who answered my question on the list borgbackup@python.org, the answer is contained in the borgbackup documentation.

see [I am seeing ‘A’ (added) status for an unchanged file](https://borgbackup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#i-am-seeing-a-added-status-for-an-unchanged-file)

*The files cache is used to determine whether Borg already “knows” / has backed up a file and if so, to skip the file from chunking. It intentionally excludes files that have a timestamp which is the same as the newest timestamp in the created archive.
...
If you want to avoid unnecessary chunking, just create or touch a small or empty file in your backup source file set (so that one has the latest timestamp, not your 50GB VM disk image) and, if you do snapshots, do the snapshot after that.*

So i decided to add a new a file in the var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice folder: passwd. The first backup (with passwd) takes the same time as the previous one: 2m35

```
root@kvm610:/var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice # time borg create --list /var/lib/libvirt/borgbackup/kvm610::essai6 /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice
U /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice_2021-08-28_06:25:22.xml
U /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice_2021-08-23_06:25:35.xml
U /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice_2021-09-02_06:25:03.xml
U /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice_2021-08-26_06:25:35.xml
U /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice_2021-08-29_06:25:14.xml
U /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice_2021-08-30_06:25:17.xml
U /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice_2021-08-31_06:25:26.xml
U /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice_2021-09-01_06:25:10.xml
U /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice_2021-08-22_06:25:08.xml
U /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice_2021-08-24_06:25:51.xml
U /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice_2021-08-25_06:25:23.xml
U /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice_2021-08-27_06:25:14.xml
U /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice.bimg-20210412-141702
U /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice.bimg-20210412-131701
U /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice.bimg-20210412-121701
U /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice.bimg-20210412-111701
U /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice.bimg-20210412-101701
U /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice.bimg-20210412-091701
U /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice.bimg-20210412-081701
U /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice.bimg-20210412-071702
A /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice.qcow2
A /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/passwd
d /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice

real    2m34,957s
user    1m44,797s
sys    0m12,468s
```

But the next backup is immediate: 0m07 !!

```
root@kvm610:/var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice # time borg create --list /var/lib/libvirt/borgbackup/kvm610::essai7 /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice
U /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice_2021-08-28_06:25:22.xml
U /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice_2021-08-23_06:25:35.xml
U /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice_2021-09-02_06:25:03.xml
U /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice_2021-08-26_06:25:35.xml
U /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice_2021-08-29_06:25:14.xml
U /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice_2021-08-30_06:25:17.xml
U /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice_2021-08-31_06:25:26.xml
U /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice_2021-09-01_06:25:10.xml
U /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice_2021-08-22_06:25:08.xml
U /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice_2021-08-24_06:25:51.xml
U /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice_2021-08-25_06:25:23.xml
U /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice_2021-08-27_06:25:14.xml
U /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice.bimg-20210412-141702
U /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice.bimg-20210412-131701
U /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice.bimg-20210412-121701
U /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice.bimg-20210412-111701
U /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice.bimg-20210412-101701
U /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice.bimg-20210412-091701
U /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice.bimg-20210412-081701
U /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice.bimg-20210412-071702
U /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/onlyoffice.qcow2
A /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice/passwd
d /var/lib/libvirt/backups/onlyoffice

real    0m0,682s
user    0m0,454s
sys    0m0,146s
```

and the qcow2 file is tagged "U", as expected!

A big thank you to Thorsten Schöning.

Ernest Chiarello.